# Why the below code is not working (StringBuffer.toString !=null)

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I am new to String World ,

I have coded as like below,

```
StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
String addressLineOne=null;
buffer.append(addreeLineOne);
if(buffer.toString!=null)
{
 system.out.println("Not NULL");
}
```

Result:Not Null;
(buffer.toString!=null)==true

Eventhough I have append null to buffer ,I am not able to identify it by having NUll check,
Code printing Not Null

Why it so?

Comment: This code does not compile, and there is nothing here that shows `StringBuffer` returning `true.`

Comment: Read the javadoc for `StringBuffer`'s [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append-java.lang.Object-), which points to the javadoc for `String.valueOf`, which should answer your question if you're asking what I think you're asking.

Comment: I think this is a good question, apart from the OP's compilation problems.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago,  `toString()` should never return `null`. What you are getting is `"null"` which is a string with the letters `n` `u` `l` `l` in it.

Comment: @EJP CODE  WILL COMPILE AS I AM ADDING A  string OBJECT INSTEAD OF null.

Comment: @Ranjithkumar He's mostly talking about the `(buffer.toString!=null)` part, you've left out the parentheses. `System` also needs to be capitalized.

Comment: @DennisMeng makesense thanks

Comment: I am not sure of what you want to do, but maybe you could test that the addressLineOne String is not null before calling the append() method ...

Comment: EJP, fivedigit, mehdi lotfi, easwee, bench - are all freaks for closing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public StringBuffer append(Object obj)
```

> Appends the string representation of the Object argument.
>
> The overall effect is exactly as if the argument were converted to a
>   string by the method String.valueOf(Object), and the characters of
>   that string were then appended to this character sequence

So `addressLineOne`, would be converted to a `String` representation, before being appended to the buffer.

> According to  [JLS, Section 15.18.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.1)
>
> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null"

implicitly, this would happen: `String.valueOf(addressLineOne)` // would give you a string with value "null" in it.

Then the characters in the string "null" would each be appended to the buffer.

**Note**: On the other hand, `new StringBuffer().append(null);` would give you an compilation error since the overloaded `append()` method's argument `null` would be ambiguous, and `String.valueOf(null)` would throw a `Null Pointer Exception`.

Comment: All has been said in the other comments to say why this is never null.

Comment: true :). But a Question expects an Answer, and i gave it one.

Comment: Sorry for this unusefull comment :) pressing <enter> did not put me on a new line (oups), and then i realized i was not in the good section (my comment was not for you, but for the guy that asked the question).

Answer (score 1):

Print the buffer inside the if condition and see for yourself:

```
if(buffer.toString()!=null){
    System.out.println("Not NULL: " + buffer.toString());
}
```

Output: Not NULL: null

Null is stored as string in the buffer - as "null" and not an actual null.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the implementation for toString() in StringBuffer.

```
public synchronized String toString() {
    return new String(value, 0, count);
    }
```

As can be seen that it is always calling new String() hence will always result in non null return